# How to compare a date to a time in python?

Tags: python, datetime, time, praw

I'm making a bot for /r/MemeEconomy and was wanting to get how old the post is and see if its older than 25 seconds (for testing purposes).

```
for submission in subreddit.new(limit=10):
    submissiontime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(submission.created_utc)
    print(submissiontime)
    print(datetime.datetime.now() - submissiontime)
```

This would output something like:

```
2018-07-08 13:37:52
0:18:53.786599
```

What I want is to be able to tell if that second value is more than 25 seconds. Something like this.

```
if submissiontime > 25seconds:
```

Comment: Can you use `if (datetime.datetime.now() - submissiontime).total_seconds() > 25:`?

Answer (score 1):

you can just compare timedeltas

```
print((datetime.datetime.now() - submissiontime)<datetime.timedelta(seconds=25))
```

`datetime.datetime.now()-other_datetime` will result in a timdelta .... and then you can just compare it .... to some other timedelta

in more recent versions of python `datetime.timedelta` also provides a `total_seconds()` method that you can use to get the "total seconds" from a timedelta and compare it to a normal integer or float